# SmartGwt drag and drop on tree component

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop, tree, smartgwt

I'm trying to move nodes form a tree to another and be able to reparent nodes and so on.
In order to get the track the drop event on a node in a tree I have registered a FolderDropHandler pn the tree:

```
tree.addFolderDropHandler(new FolderDropHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFolderDrop(FolderDropEvent folderDropEvent) {
                TreeNode parentFolder = folderDropEvent.getFolder();
                TreeNode droppedItem =  folderDropEvent.getNodes()[0];

            }
        });
```

This works fine, I'm notified when nodes are dropped on other nodes, but I am not notified when I drop on the root node (or an empty tree with just the root node). How can i handle this case? Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have experience with drag and drop but did you just use setShowRoot or did you declared a TreeNode with setIsFolder(true) and use setRoot() to attach it to the tree?